# Granting Access to Reporting Services to create custom Roles

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

See image.

How does a dba go about granting access to the screen shown.

This is for a generic user using their AD credentials to access the 'Reporting Services' on a particular server. This is so that the generic user is able to create new 'roles' for SSRS. Currently only the administrator has access.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you showed belongs to connection to SQL Server which manage sql databases.

In most cases the reporting services installed on the SQL SERVER but it not mandatory. The reporting services server can be a dedicated one apart of the SQL Server.

The image you shown is the connection window to SQL SERVER
There Two option to perform a login:

1. Windows Authentication - (Uses the loged on user to the machine) A DBA needs to allow this user or a group which this user is a memeber in to connect the SQL server. In addition he need to configure which database is available to him.
2. The second option is to set a SQL User and to give him permission to manage databases.

[Setup a login on SQL SERVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx)

The Reporting services has Report manager URL, which allows to manage report existing or add new reports ect..

In order to allow users to access the URL, you need to allow a specific user or a group to access the report server manager

[Granting permission to the report manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156014.aspx)

**How to grant YOU access to a database**

1. Open SQL Management Studio
2. Your DBA should login with his permission (sa/admin permission)
3. Expand `"Security"` Tab
4. Right click on "Login" folder and choose `"New Login"`
5. Click on the `"Search"` button next to the `"login name:"` field
6. In the text area search for you AD username
7. Click "Ok"
8. Choose desire master database
9. On the left panel choose the `"User Mapping"` option
10. Choose desire Database on the upper section
11. Select proper permission on the bottom section for example `"db_owner"`

After this you can create a data source with Yours user name

Does it what have you looked for?

Comment: OP is looking to eventually create custom Roles in SSRS - this is performed through Management Studio - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156293.aspx. You can see in the screen shot Management Studio is explicitly connecting to a Reporting Services instance. The question is what permission is required to be able to connect this way.

Comment: I understand that a user can log in using their AD credentials or a user name and password that does have access. My question is, how does MY dba grant ME access, as currently I cannot log in using my AD credentials and my dba has not been able to grant me access. I need to advise him where he needs to go....

Comment: I have added the steps for adding user to connect a database, let me know if that what you looked for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be assigned to the *System Administrator* **System Role** by default:

[Connect to a Report Server in Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159797%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

[image]

So adding users/groups to that role should allow them to connect and create new roles. They'll be admins on the Report Server itself, but at least not on the underlying server.

Comment: So if my dba put my AD login in the box above and ticked the System Administrator box, I would be able to log in as myself in the window attached to my question?

Comment: Yes. By default the privilege is assigned to the BUILTIN\Administrators group, i.e. server admins only. Getting yourself assigned as above will give you certain admin privileges over Reporting Services but not the server itself - better for security that way.

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this issue?

Comment: My AD login does have 'System Administrator' however I can not log into reporting services through the window in my question still.

Comment: I spun up a VM to test this out; with a non-administrator user I could log into Reporting Services but couldn't create roles. With System Administrator I could both log in and create roles. So in a simple test it seemed to make a difference, but I understand that there's not necessarily a comparison between an artifical environment and a live implementation. Sorry it didn't help.